# Pass Data To a Javascript File

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript file linked to a HTML file, it has bunch of parameters which I want to change according to the parameter user selected or clicked.

```
var ArticleAnimator = ArticleAnimator || {
  canScroll:          true,
  initialLoad:        true, 
  animationDuration:  500, 
  postCount:          5, //Row count of a SQL table
  currentPostIndex:   1, //Data from $id=$_GET['id'];
  postCache:          {},
  pageTemplate:       null,
};
```

My question is how can I change these values I have got the values I want using PHP but want to change it in this javascript file

Comment: I didn't get answer from the post..

Comment: It tells you: within a Php processed file just as usual. In a separate file you have to use  variables.